# How do we add dylib with cmake into a project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I am trying to build an xcode project using cmake, but I am having some problems including dylib (libsqlite3.dylib).

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following cmake macro to find libsqlite3: [github Page](https://github.com/LuaDist/libsqlite3/blob/master/cmake/FindSQLite3.cmake)

And then use:

```
 target_link_libraries(myexecutable, ${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES})
```

To add link your application to the sqlite3 library. And then you need to regenerate your XCode project file.

Comment: actually i am getting this error now:   Cannot specify link libraries for target "/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib" which
  is not built by this project.

  CMake does not support this but it used to work accidentally and is being
  allowed for compatibility.

  Policy CMP0016 is not set: target_link_libraries() reports error if only
  argument is not a target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0016" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Comment: got it to work, just my target was empty that was why it failed, thx!